# Why isn't my NSTimer calling my method upon expiration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am using an NSTimer to call a method which is titled Lose. I had a timer which when it ran out, it called Lose, but I lost everything due to a hard drive error. After trying to code it all again, I can't seem to get the method to be called.

```
Timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:timeMax target:self selector:@selector(Lose) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Lose is declared in my .h file, like this:

```
-(void)Lose;
```

Also, my method looks like this:

```
-(void)Lose{

Text.hidden = NO;
scoreLabel.hidden = NO;
Target.hidden = YES;
Targetx.hidden = YES;


if (Score > highScoreNumber) {
    highScoreAchieved.hidden = NO;
    highScoreNumber = Score;
    }

}
```

The variable timeMax is an int declared in my .h file, like last time.
whenever a target is tapped in my game, timeMax becomes .03 seconds shorter. I do it like this:

```
timeMax = 5 - (Score * 0.03);
```

I don't remember it looking different before the massive hardware failure, but why isnt it working?

Comment: Please take the time to read [the objective-c naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW1).

Comment: What is the value of score? Is there a chance that `timeMax` is in the negative?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin timeMax starts at 5, when the start button is pressed. Score begins at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to schedule the timer on a run loop or just use this line instead which schedules it for you:

```
Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeMax
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(Lose)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
```

It's also a good idea to always back up your code...which reminds me.